Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'
I am implementing an API that interacts with the SharePoint List, and retrieve the data collection. Somehow the interface does not return statement.

    private getCarouselListContent = () => {   
    try {
       let requestUrl = `${this.props.absoluteURL}/_api/web/Lists/
 GetByTitle('${this.props.listName}')/Items`;
        this.props.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
       .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) : Promise<ISliderCarouselDemoState> =>{
         if(response.ok){
           return response.json();
         } 
       }).then((item: { value: any; } | null) => {      
         if (item!=null){ 
         try{            
               this.setState(({  
                 value: item.value             
               }));            
             }
             catch(err){   
                   
             }
           }
         });
        } catch (error) {    
       console.log('error in service ', error);  
     }
   }


The problem is that the anonymous function you use to handle your GET response says that it will return a Promise that will eventually resolve to something that implements ISliderCarouselDemoState.
// this function says that it will return a promise
(response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<ISliderCarouselDemoState> => {

}

However, inside the function, you only conditionally return something:
// this function says that it will return a promise
(response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise <ISliderCarouselDemoState> => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    // what happens if the response is not OK?
    // nothing gets returned, but your function definition
    // says that something _will_ get returned
}

You could maybe fix it by doing something like
(response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<ISliderCarouselDemoState> => {
    return new Promise<ISliderCarouselDemoState>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            reject('Oops, something went wrong')
        }
    })
}

However, I have a feeling that that might not work either because I'm guessing that the JSON you get from response.json() does not actually match what's defined in ISliderCarouselDemoState.
Also, to be able to conditionally pass null on to your next chained function, you might have to do something like this... (and keep in mind that response.json() is itself an async function, so you have to handle that in an async way as well)
(response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<any | null> => {
    return new Promise<any | null>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
                resolve(responseJSON);
            })
        } else {
            // a reject here will stop the chaining,
            // so to move on to the next function,
            // you have to resolve the promise
            resolve(null);
        }
    })
}

An easier way might be to make the whole getCarouselListContent function an async function so you can use await inside it. Makes for much easier reading:
private getCarouselListContent = async () => {
    try {
        let requestUrl = `${this.props.absoluteURL}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('${this.props.listName}')/Items`;

        const response: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.props.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);

        if (response.ok) {
            const responseJSON: any = await response.json();
            try {
                this.setState(({
                    value: responseJSON.value
                }));
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in service ', error);
    }
}


I had another thought... you might be able to fix it just by doing
(response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<ISliderCarouselDemoState> => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    
    return null;
}

since that will return the json() Promise if the response is OK, and null if not...
I still think making the overall function async so you can use await makes it all much more readable, though.
I need more coffee this morning...
